# Create an app lifetime object (not possible to be deallocated) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an object from a class. And I want it life time to be the app life time. I mean I want it not be deallocated since the app is running.
the class that I want to make an instance from:

```
extension Post {

    @NSManaged var userId: Int
    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var body: String

}

class Post: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

   override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        title = ""
        userId = 0
        id = 0
        body = ""

    }
}
```

Comment: A singleton NSManagedObject subclass doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Paulw11 posts are stored using CoreData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object that keeps a strong pointer to itself cannot be deallocated:

```
class Permanent {
    private var ref: Permanent?

    init() {
        ref = self
    }

    deinit {
        // This will never be called
        print("Permanent deinit")
    }
}

func test() {
    var a = [Permanent(), Permanent()]
    print(a.count)

    print("free the items")
    a = []
    print("end of test")
}

test()
```

Output:

> ```
> 2
> free the items
> end of test
> ```

If you comment out the `ref = self` line:

Output:

> ```
> 2
> free the items
> Permanent deinit
> Permanent deinit
> end of test
> ```